# Run python script and passing variables using PHP

Tags: python, php

Hi am having trouble passing a variable from PHP to python. It is not displaying on the webpage

PHP

```
<?php 
  $item='example';
  exec("python pytest.py $item");
?>
```

Python

```
import sys
print(sys.argv[1])
```

I am running WAMP and both the PHP and Python file is in the same working directory. However, nothing is displayed on the PHP webpage. Please help, thank you.

Comment: Do you have [PHP error reporting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display) enabled? Maybe it throws an exception. Maybe you do not have the rights to execute such commands? Other logs might help as well (Python and/or System).

Answer (score 0):

I think the only thing you are missing in your PHP script is `echo`.

If you call `exec("python pytest.py $item");` PHP won't just print the output of the called command.

You need to `echo shell_exec("python pytest.py $item");`.

The difference between `exec` and `shell_exec` is that shell_exec will return the output of the command but `exec` won't. You can read more about it here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php and https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php.

Also make sure the user, which is running the PHP-File, has permissions on the pytest.py file.

Answer (score -1):

To call a Python file from within a PHP file, you need to call it using the shell_exec function.

For example

```
<?php
    $command = escapeshellcmd('/usr/custom/test.py');
    $output = shell_exec($command);
    echo $output;
?>
```

This will call the script. But in your script at the top, you'll need to specify the interpreter as well. So in your py file, add the following line at the top:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

Alternatively you can also provide the interpreter when executing the command.

For example

```
<?php
    $command = escapeshellcmd('python3 /usr/custom/test.py');
    $output = shell_exec($command);
    echo $output;
?>
```

other alternate way to do is

```
ob_start();
passthru('/usr/bin/python2.7 /srv/http/assets/py/switch.py arg1 arg2');
$output = ob_get_clean();
```

Comment: Hi there, may i check if my python file is in the same directory do I still need to define the path or can I define the python file straight away

Comment: yes you may need to use full path or relative path.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but none of it is working for me.